# SharePoint Server 2k7 / Office 2003 Integration problem (CT prob.)

Tags: sharepoint, moss, types, wss

**I have a bit of problem with MOSS (uptodate under 2003 r2) and Office 2003 integration. Customer particularly wants Office 2003.**

**Problem**

So, when you make "new" document in the document center and document template is triggered and you hit "ok". In here everything is fine.

Your doc is read and you hit "save" in Office Word 2003 and then there should be window where *content type specified metadata field window - where you can enter your information*, but there comes window where all CTs metadata fields are fully listed, I mean ALL listed. It supposed to list particular CT`s metafields info in a window where you can enter some data.

**Project** is typical "non code" implementation and we just had basic customization according to the problem.

**Customizations(fully):**

- Lists
- Content Types
- Fields

*Problem disappears* when you manually modified your custom list definition( or document center def.) in SC options. Add CTs to the list or just modified the list in some way.
Or it will work when you just use default defs.

I think the problem is in the Content Types some how... Dunno why but i assume and don`t know specific

*If you have some tips for this problem it would be nice you to drop out some.*

SAV

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the schema.xml and the content types before and after using [SharePoint Manager 2007](http://www.codeplex.com/spm)? Maybe it could give you a clue.

Answer (score 0):

I know the issue too (not the resolution though). I took the schema.xml out from a list that was working and checked the schema.xml and noticed that in the schema's Fields was ContentType-field added.

ContentType-field's ID was pointing to the ContentType-field from WSS' own fieldswss.xml but the funny thing was that its type was changed from Text to Choice. In the choices was listed all the content types associated with the list. I did try to add similar field to my schema-file but it did nothing :(

I should also point out that we don't use custom document templates in our content types and that CTs inherit from Document-CT. Also we don't necessarily have to modify list's settings to make it work but also going into site settings > content types and updating our CT (just pressing OK) fixes things. If we create a new list after updating CT the new list doesn't work.